# MinGW-w64 Проблемы с компиляцией

Tags: mingw-w64

Вот код:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__

    #ifndef USE_PLATFORM_LINUX

        #define USE_PLATFORM_LINUX

        #include <dlfcn.h>

        .....

    #endif // USE_PLATFORM_LINUX



 #endif // __GNUC__
```

Ошибка:

```
.../Platforms/Linux.h:10:18: fatal error: dlfcn.h: No such file or directory
         #include <dlfcn.h>
```

Лишь один вопрос - как так?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Вам говорят, что невозможно найти файл `dlfcn.h` - вы с этим не согласны или что?

Comment: __GNUC__ на винде не определяется. Он вообще не должен пытаться что-то инклюдить в этом блоке. Получается препроцессор не срабатывает...

Comment: MinGW это порт gcc и логично, что `__GNUC__` задефайнен.

Comment: Блок действителен. `__GNUC__` в MinGW объявлена, т.к. этот компилятор, по сути, является компилятором gcc.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Теперь понятно. Просто в VS Сode оно неподсвечивалось, типа не определено, и меня это спутало.